# How to work out the probability using standard deviation in python

Tags: python, statistics, probability, standard-deviation

I have a list of students. I have their attendance rates for last year and their current attendance for this year so far. I am trying to work out the probability of them being less than 90% by the end of the year. Below is my data:

```
Name  %LastYear AttendedSoFarThisYear  SessionsSoFarThisYear  %SoFarThisYear SessionsNeeded  SessionsLeft
Ethan 97%       218                    232                    94%            52              68
Molly 91%       202                    232                    87%            101             68
Henry 95%       226                    232                    97%            44              68
```

So at the moment I am working it out by doing SessionsNeeded divided by SessionsLeft, then multiplying by 100. So for Ethan that is 76% likely, Molly is 148% likely and Henry is 65% likely to get below 90%.

However I don't think this way of working out the probability is very fair because at the start of the year, everyone will have a very high probability percentage as they haven't completed any sessions. But really I want it to take into account their previous year attendance, so that at the start of the year, Molly will have a higher probability than Ethan.

It also needs to take into account their current attendance rates so far. As Henry is actually attending 97% of the time, it is probable he will continue to do so. Whereas Molly is just under 87%, it is not likely she will catch up.

Does anyone have any ideas of I could work this out using this data? Preferably in python, or even in excel?

Comment: This is not a question about python or programming, but rather about statistics. Even so, take a look at [this video from 3b1b](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8idr1WZ1A7Q) for some motivation on how to think about the probability distribution of probabilities.

Comment: If you agree that the question is about statistics, you should probably move it to a more dedicated community like https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could weight the importance of previous and current year attendance based on the completion of the current year.

`completion = SessionsSoFarThisYear/TotalSessionsInThisYear`

The attendance probability for a student would be equal to:

`P_attendence(student) = LastYearAttendence(student) * (1 - completion) + ThisYearAttendence(student) * completion`

**Edit:**

Next step would be to get the difference between `SessionsNeeded` and `SessionsLeft` corrected by student's attendance `P_attendance`:

`delta_days(student) = (SessionsLeft * P_attendance(student)) - SessionsNeeded(student)`

Finally, to get the probability of a student fulfilling the attendance requirement of 90%, use a clamped logistic function with `L = 1 and x0 = 0`:

[Logistic Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)

`P_passing(student) = 0% if delta_days(student) <= 0, else log_f(delta_days(student))`

For all negative `delta_days` it returns 0% probability of fulfillment, meaning that with the current estimate of student's attendance, there is no chance of passing. The higher the attendance (estimated) and the more days left to skip the higher probability of passing this year.

**Edit2:**
The 90% threshold is hidden in `SessionsNeeded` used to calculate `delta_days`.

Comment: Hi @MightestDuck. Thank you for your edits, I have just implemented them. delta_days(student) = -41.21 for Molly, 21.65 for Henry and 12.39 for Ethan. How do I implement a clamped logistic function on those numbers?

Comment: Hi @Pippa97, a simple function with one if statement will do the work. If delta_days(student) < 0, then return 0.0, else use [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) formula from the wikipedia with delta_days(student) as an argument x, the midpoint x0 = 0, maximum curve's value L = 1 and steepness k = 1. Try it out and adjust the steepness, smaller k makes the curve approach linearity, larger k makes it steeper.

Comment: Thanks @MightestDuck is there a built in logistic function in python I could use?

Comment: Not sure. Writing it yourself shouldn't be a problem - it's a one liner.